# Python Pandas-Automating Data Gathering from Website

Tags: python, pandas, database, automation, data-science

I'm trying to make a script that can read through a table of company names from one website and take the names of each company and put them in an url (the url exists, and it contains more data specific to each company. This data is what I want to analyze).

However, I cannot get the names to be put in the url without python also putting in parts of the table, giving me the error below:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests

url1 = "http://openinsider.com/latest-penny-stock-buys"
df1 = pd.read_html(url1)
table = df1[11]
# sorting
n = np.quantile(table["Qty"], [0.99])
print("20th percentile: ", n)
q = table.sort_values("Qty", ascending=False)
name = q["Ticker"].str.replace("\d+", "")
page = requests.get(url1)
name = table["Ticker"]
# Buyers for the company
url = "http://openinsider.com/"
for entry in name:  # <- Question starts here
    name = entry + 1
    table2 = pd.read_html(url + str(name))
    df2 = table2[11]
    print(df2)
```

> Error: InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/0      OPK\n1     VEII\n2      NGM\n3     STRR\n4
> IMRA\n      ... \n95     NaN\n96    CDXC\n97     PED\n98     FOA\n99    CAMP\nName:
> Ticker, Length: 100, dtype: object' (found at least ' ')```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for-loop`:

- remove `name = entry + 1`
- replace `url+str(name)` with `url + entry`

And so, you get the expected output printed:

```
     X          Filing Date  Trade Date Ticker           Insider Name Title  \
0  NaN  2022-10-21 19:03:38  2022-10-19   MIST     Wills Robert James   Dir   
1  NaN  2022-10-21 19:02:50  2022-10-20   MIST    Pasternak Richard C   Dir   
2    M  2022-10-21 19:02:01  2022-10-20   MIST       Liebert Debra K.   Dir   
3  NaN  2022-10-21 19:01:16  2022-10-19   MIST  Tomsicek Michael John   Dir   
4  NaN  2022-09-09 16:15:34  2022-09-07   MIST    Rtw Investments, LP   10%   
5  NaN  2022-09-09 16:15:34  2022-09-07   MIST    Rtw Investments, LP   10%   
6    D  2022-06-01 21:32:38  2022-05-31   MIST           Truex Paul F   Dir   

     Trade Type  Price      Qty    Owned   ΔOwn         Value  1d  1w  1m  6m  
0  P - Purchase  $4.93    15000    15000    New      +$73,950 NaN NaN NaN NaN  
1  P - Purchase  $5.20    10000    10000    New      +$52,000 NaN NaN NaN NaN  
2  P - Purchase  $5.28    14000    14127  >999%      +$73,940 NaN NaN NaN NaN  
3  P - Purchase  $5.32    15000    15000    New      +$79,800 NaN NaN NaN NaN
...
```

Comment: Thank you I can't believe the solution was that simple I was really overthinking it!